# Кроссбраузерное решение для autoplay mp3

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, аудио

Здравствуйте уважаемы форумчане. Не подскажете ли вы как прийти к данному решению? Собственно сама суть в том что бы при получении сообщения воспроизводился секундный mp3 сигнал. Или может что более напутствующее подскажите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример через библиотеку howler.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.1.1/howler.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var sound = new Howl({
      src: ['example.mp3']//ссылка на аудио которое нужно воспроизвести
    });


    function message() {
        sound.play()
    }


    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        message()
    });
```